# Animating line graph with circular points

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, cashapelayer, cgpath

I have stumbled upon an interesting problem and I am not sure how to solve it. I have a line graph on which data points are marked with circular dots. At the moment I am creating one `CAShapeLayer` for the line itself and also `CAShapeLayer` for each dot.

The line is being animated with the strokeEnd animation key path. And it is working. However, the slightly negative effect is that once I open the graph I see all the data points already drawn and then a line is being animated through them.

Ideally I would like to change this behaviour in such a way that at the beginning nothing is shown and as the line gets animated data points are being drawn once the line passes through them.

I was thinking about this problem for some time now and I cannot find an elegant way of solving it. It seems to me that there should be a fairly easy way of achieving what I want. Maybe I should create a compounded path (but then how do I specify that a line needs to be stroked whereas dots need to be filled?).

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to handle this.

Assuming that the X increments of your graph are constant, and you're using linear timing, you could simply divide the total animation time by the number of data-points, and calculate the times when you need to add points to the graph when the line progresses to that X position. Simply add dot shape layers to the parent view's layer at the appropriate time intervals.

You could also change your drawing method to add new line segments to your graph path one at a time, on a timer, and add dot shapes at the same time. That would give you a step-by-step animation rather than a smooth line drawing.